# Can't Start IDLE python GUI in windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to build python application and it turns to its end. But unfortunately I can't even open or start the the python GUI. It just blinks and shutdown. How to solve this trouble? Can anybody help?

Comment: Which python version you have installed?

Comment: How are you attempting to start it?  Via the start menu, in Windows Explorer through the folder where the executable is, or command line?

Comment: version 2.7 and I tried to attempt start it from start menu , Not from command line...

Comment: If IDLE does not start under Windows, my advice would be to deinstall Python and reinstall. Even if you can fix it, it is caused by a messy install and something else could be broken and smash you later...

Comment: can you start python from the command line (run 'cmd' from the start menu and type 'python' at the prompt; 'exit()' to quit python)? I'm trying to figure out if it's your python installation or just IDLE, or maybe just the start menu shortcut.